# Cómo puedo leer un fichero en donde la primera lineal sea el numero de líneas a leer y guardar los datos en una variable

Tags: java

Este es mi código, la función es poder utilizar cualquier numero al principio y ejecutar la formula.
Tengo estos datos en fina en el txt: 5 0.48 0.82 0.69 0.67 0.00 El objetivo es efectuar formula xi = 95 + 5(ri) para cada uno.

```js
package df;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class df {

    static double todoRI;
    static int vida;
    static String ri;
    static double xi;
    static PrintWriter pw;

    public static void main (String [] args )throws IOException { // Llamos a los metodos para su ejecución.
        
        lectura();
        algoritmo();
    }
          
    
        public static void lectura() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { // Metodo para la entrada en formato .txt.

            FileReader fr = new FileReader ("Archivos/Prueba01.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
            String linea = br.readLine();
            vida = Integer.parseInt(linea);
            System.out.println("Vida del Algoritmo: " + vida + ". ");
            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
                for(int j = 0; j < vida; j++){
                    ri = linea; 
                    linea = br.readLine();
                    int z;
                    z = j+1;
                    System.out.println("R" + z + ": " + ri + ". ");  // Este valor lo quiero utilizar en el metodo algoritmo.
                }        
}              
        public static void algoritmo() throws FileNotFoundException { // Metodo del algoritmo.
            
            todoRI = Double.parseDouble(ri); 
            pw = new PrintWriter("Archivos/Salida01.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < vida; i++) {
                xi = 95 + 5 * todoRI;
                escritura(i);    
            }
                pw.close();   
        }
   
        public static void escritura (int i){ // Llamo a "i". Esta contiene el recorrido (Iteraciones). Metodo para la salida en .txt.
            
            int x;
            x = i+1;
            pw.println("Medición: " + x + "    ri: " + ri + "    Temperatura C°: " + xi); // Estructura de tabla.
        }  
}
```

Tengo problemas para ejecutarlo me marca error al momento de escribir el fichero. Seguramente me falta implementar algo en el método lectura o tengo errores al momento de implementar en el método algoritmo.

[image: Me da esta salida, tengo algún error de conversión pero me cicle]